# How to get Produkt ID or SKU from URL?

Tags: product, url

I'm not on a product page (custom module) and I have the URL of a product page.
Is it possible to get the product ID from a URL?

I checked Mage::getUrl but that seem to generate URLs - I need it the other way round.
Is there a possibility to do that? Via the rewrite table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the product ID as the following example, since you already have the path included the URL.

```
$oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->loadByRequestPath($vPath);

$iProductId = $oRewrite->getProductId();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254789/magento-load-product-by-url

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, that worked fine for me.

Comment: Glad it helped.